# MS SQL match table on multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I want to join two tables based on multiple rows, and can't find the correct way to do this.

The tables looks something like this :

**table1**

```
Id  Location    LocationNo  
 1         1             1  
 1         2             2  
 1         3             3
 2         1             1
 2         2             2
 3         2             1
 3         1             2
 3         3             3
 4         1             1
 4         2             2
 4         3             3
 4         4             4
```

**table2**

```
    Location    LocationNo  
           1             1  
           2             2  
           3             3
```

I want to get the Id from table1 that match exactly the rows in table2.
I expect that the return should be Id 1.

I've tried the query bellow but the result are not the one expected.

```
SELECT t.Id
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table2 t2
               WHERE  t1.LocationId = t2.LocationId
                      AND t1.LocationNo = t2.LocationNo)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT : 
**table2**

```
    Location    LocationNo  
           1             1  
           2             2  
           3             3
           5             4
```

For this case I expect that the result should be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
          FROM   (SELECT Count(1) cnt,
                         id
                  FROM   Table1 a
                  GROUP  BY id) a
                 JOIN (SELECT t1.Id,
                              Count(1) cnt
                       FROM   table1 t1
                              JOIN table2 t2
                                ON t1.[Location] = t2.[Location]
                                   AND t1.LocationNo = t2.LocationNo
                       GROUP  BY t1.Id
                       HAVING Count(1) = (SELECT Count(1)
                                          FROM   table2)) b
                   ON a.cnt = b.cnt
                      AND a.Id = b.id)
  WITH tot_count
       AS (SELECT Count(1) cnt,
                  id
           FROM   #Table1 a
           GROUP  BY id),
       sub_cnt
       AS (SELECT t1.Id,
                  Count(1) cnt
           FROM   table1 t1
                  JOIN table2 t2
                    ON t1.[Location] = t2.[Location]
                       AND t1.LocationNo = t2.LocationNo
           GROUP  BY t1.Id
           HAVING Count(1) = (SELECT Count(1)
                              FROM   table2))
  SELECT b.id
  FROM   tot_count a
         JOIN sub_cnt b
           ON a.cnt = b.cnt
              AND a.Id = b.id
ELSE
  SELECT NULL
```

Comment: The first cte shouldn't also be groupped by Id?<br> Also the alias a should t1.<br>

Comment: @CodrutMerlusca - yeah missed it, Updated

Comment: @Y.B. Did you read this *I expect that the return should be Id 1.* Whether your query will return only Id `1`

Comment: I just tested, but it doesn't match exactly. If table2 has one more row with other locations that aren't in table1 the result will be also 1. I expect it to be null.

Comment: @CodrutMerlusca - can you update the sample data and expected result with the above scenario

Comment: @CodrutMerlusca - check now

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Distinct t1.Id  --< Use Distinct to return unique values only
From table1 t1
Inner Join table2 t2   --< Use Inner Join instead of "where exists"
  On t1.LocationId = t2.LocationId
 AND t1.LocationNo = t2.LocationNo
```

**Update**: It actually turned out to be more interesting than that: here we are looking for the exact match on all rows:

```
Select t1.Id
From table1 t1
Left Join table2 t2 --< Left Join to register NULLs from table2
  On t1.LocationId = t2.LocationId
 AND t1.LocationNo = t2.LocationNo
Group By t1.Id
Having  --< Number of records from each table equals the count of matching criteria rows
    Count(t1.LocationId) = (Select Count(*) From table2)
AND Count(t2.LocationId) = (Select Count(*) From table2)
```

Source data for testing:

```
With table1 As (
    Select * From (Values 
     (1, 1, 1), 
     (1, 2, 2), 
     (1, 3, 3),
     (2, 1, 1),
     (2, 2, 2),
     (3, 2, 1),
     (3, 1, 2),
     (3, 3, 3),
     (4, 1, 1),
     (4, 2, 2),
     (4, 3, 3),
     (4, 4, 4)
    ) V (Id, LocationId, LocationNo)
), table2 As (
    Select * From (Values 
        (1, 1), 
        (2, 2), 
        (3, 3)
    ) V (LocationId, LocationNo)
)
```

Comment: nothing in your query has the alias `t` (in `t.Id`)

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks. Missed that problem in the OP's script.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [Inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

```
select t1.Id -- or t2.id, depends which table you want the ID from
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
on t1.LocationId = t2.LocationId 
and t1.LocationNo = t2.LocationNo
```